# Error message when displaying PrimeNG Galleria component

Tags: angular, primeng

I recently upgraded my angular app to version 16 so I also upgraded my PrimeNg components. I am currently using version 16.0.0-rc.2 ( the only version that would install on angular 16) and I am running in the following error message and the component does not work:

[image]

It is generated by this:

```
 <p-galleria [value]="images" [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions" [containerStyle]="{ 'max-width': '640px' }" [numVisible]="5">
                <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
                    <img [src]="item.itemImageSrc" style="width:490px; height: 480px;" />
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="thumbnail" let-item>
                    <div class="grid grid-nogutter justify-content-center">
                        <img [src]="item.thumbnailImageSrc" style="width:80px; height: 60px;" />
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-galleria>
```

If I comment out the html element, the error goes away.

Thanks for any suggestion on how to address this issue.

Comment: That's a bug in PrimeNG: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13124

Comment: Thanks @skink.  That's a bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with primeng 16.0.0, and after upgrading to primeng 16.0.1, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with p-galleria. Just update primeNg version `"primeng": "^16.0.0-rc.2" to "primeng": "^16.0.1"`, this problem disappeared.